# In C, is there a way to take multiple user inputs from one line command line prompt?

Tags: c, unix

I'm wondering in C is there a way to prompt the user to enter 2 different values,
and then store those two values separately, all in one user entry. For example:

```
Enter your age and blood type : 34 AB
```

Then we store the two enties separately like

```
fgets(string,string, 64, 64, stdin);
```

Clearly THIS won't work, but is there a way possible in C. I'm very new to C (2 days). I know in Java you can use the args[] defined in the main and grab command line entries by index, where each space in the user's input would be a different element in the args array.

Comment: Check the scanf() function (and its siblings). My C is a bit rusty so I won't chance my arm at an example.

Comment: [Command-line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1285/command-line-arguments#t=201609230546311317197)

Comment: "Yes, as many programs do".

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: The OP most likely refers to data entered via the terminal  and not to arguments passed to a program on start-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`args` in main works in C too, though the conventional name is `argv` (argument vector), as in `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

You can also use scanf, as in `scanf("%d %s", &age, blood_type);`.

A third, and usually recommended way when processing user input, is to separate input from analyzing the input, as in:

```
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
sscanf(line, "%d %s", &age, blood_type);
```

A more complete version of the above code, with error checking:

```
char line[100];
int age;
char blood_type[100];
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL ||
    sscanf(line, "%d %s", &age, blood_type) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read age and blood type. Sorry.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Since `line` contains at most 99 characters, plus the '\0' that marks the end of the string, we cant get an overflow in the variable `blood_type`. Otherwise, we could use `%99s` instead of just `%s` to limit the number of characters that can be put into `blood_type`.

Comment: I'd add a note about checking result of *scanf*, because if there is parse error, the input variables are left unmodified (so possibly uninitialized, leading to UB). I'd also add a note about providing buffer size for *%s* to avoid buffer overflow by long user input.

Answer (score 0):

The best way by far is

```
char string[100];

if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin) != NULL) {
    // split the string here to extract the "n" values
}
```

Comment: You don't actually answer the question.

Comment: @IngoBürk Why not? Do you want me to give the code? The question is whether or not it is possible to read a single line and extract multiple values from it. I think I did answer.

Comment: The question clearly involves *how* to separate the multiple arguments. Trying to lawyer the question isn't going to remove my downvote here.

Comment: Dear Ingo Bürk, what you are doing by downvoting is wrong! You are demotivatiing the others to invest their time to the problem and recommend another solutions which may also be in scope of the interest of the author. Always remember it is not always easy to identify a need and form a proper question. This is not a binary wold yes no to judje like you do. I personally disrespect so non-constructive comments like yours.

Comment: @IngoBürk I fully agree with dmi - the question is "Is there a way (...)", so the answer is "yes, there is", and iharob added an example of the other way. Really dont understand reason of Your downvote.

Comment: @dmi iharob didn't provide »another solution«, he just tried to be smart and non-constructive by being intentionally picky about words and misinterpreting the question. The old »Is it possible» – »Yes« game is a funny joke, but it should stay in the comments. It is fully clear what the *actual* question is and this answer was absolutely unnecessary. iharob has 39k, he knows better than that.

Comment: At least iharob invested his time to think deeper and I find this a great effort. It might not be perfect, and in my opinion this is acceptable. Was it useful or not to solve the issue - let the topic starter decide.But you've done this instead of him. There is no need to judj iharob from outside, this is hopefully not a court, otherwise this is IMHO a wrong recource to share experience.

Comment: @dmi We have a voting feature on SO for a reason. It's there to be used, so please don't argue that it shouldn't be used. If you care about silencing downvotes, please bring it up over in meta where it belongs. This discussion is getting out of hand – I've explained my reasons for the downvote and as long as the answer doesn't change, neither will my vote.

Comment: @dmi: the community gets to decide what is useful or not, by voting. Which is what Ingo did here, and even provided feedback as to why they think a post is not useful. Voting (either way) is an important task everyone plays. However, comments are not for extended discussion; take that to a chatroom or [meta].

Comment: @IngoBürk I don't want you to remove your downvote, I am not a dictator and your are free to express what you think. I just, don't want to delete the answer because I don't consider it a bad answer. Not because it's my answer, but because I don't think it's a bad answer.

Answer (score -1):

One additional option (depends on your environment) - man `getopt`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653362/in-c-is-there-a-way-to-take-multiple-user-inputs-from-one-line-command-line-pro#comment66610200_39653362